# jquery validate accept rule not working

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery validate rule that is forcing the firstname to be at least 2 characters long (wrong behavior). I want to allow firstname to be a single character.

```
rules: {
firstname:{
required:true,
accept: "[a-zA-Z `'-]+"
}
```

Comment: Why would you allow a single space to be a valid first name?

Comment: well, I wouldn't want to allow that, and if the accept statement can be modified so that a space cannot be the first character, then all the better.

Comment: Here is link to jsFiddle. The code doesn't work there and I'm new to jsFiddle so I don't know why. Anyway, at least you can see the code. http://jsfiddle.net/jackalbright/xbH8R/

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
rules: {
  firstname:{
  required:true,
  minlength: 0,
  accept: "[a-zA-Z `'-]+"
}
```

Set minimum length to 0.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but no luck. I also tried minlength:1 since this actually made a little more sense, but the rule is still requiring that I input at least 2 characters.

Comment: I will try. I have never used jsFiddle. I guess it's time I learned, eh?